# Can get correct statistics from fastparquet

Tags: dask, fastparquet

I am getting None statistics (min / max) when reading file from S3 using fastparquet.
When calling

```
fp.ParquetFile(fn=path, open_with=myopen).statistics['min']
```

Most of the values are None, and some of the values are valid.

However, when I read the same file with other framework, I am able to get the correct min/max for all values.

How can I get all the statistics?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The full set of row groups are available as the list

```
pf = fp.ParquetFile(fn=path, open_with=myopen)
pf.row_groups
```

and each row group has a `.columns` attribute, which in turn have `meta_data`; so you can dig around to see what the individual min/max of the columns are.